# How is custom injected DLL being removed from Notepad's address space?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, import, hook

I have a separate injector and it injects the DLL into the address space of `notepad.exe` and also executes the operations. However, after a certain moment `notepad.exe` deletes the DLL from its address space (at least it is not part of its address space when I monitor it with the process explorer). Does anyone know why this behaviour occurs?

One additional question: `ntdll.dll` is not part of the IAT, but when I monitor it with API Monitor, it actually calls functions directly from the Native API. I don't think these are dynamically loaded functions. When it calls `CreateFileA`/`CreateFileW`, this wrapper function calls `NtCreateFile`, but quite often it also calls `NtCreatFile` directly, but this module is not part of the IAT.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

FILE* file_pointer;
FILE* write_file;
HMODULE array_modules[1024];
DWORD number_bytes;
DWORD WB = 0;
WCHAR BUFFER[1024]; //Unicode characters
int i;
char BUFFER_OUTPUT[] = "test1"; //Unicode characters
typedef int(WINAPI* Func_Pointer)(HANDLE, LPCVOID, DWORD, LPDWORD, LPOVERLAPPED);
Func_Pointer Original_VA_WriteFile = NULL;

BOOL WriteFile_HOOK(HANDLE hFile, LPCVOID lpBuffer, DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
    /*
    int HANDLE = open("C:\\Users\\Mikail\\Documents\\outputfileAPI.txt");
    if (HANDLE == NULL) {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        fprintf(file_pointer, "Handle not retrieved %s", error);
    }
    else {
        fopen_s(&file_pointer, "C:\\Users\\Mikail\\Documents\\outputfileAPI.txt", "w+");
        fprintf(file_pointer, "Handle retrieved");
        WriteFile(HANDLE, &BUFFER_OUTPUT, sizeof(BUFFER_OUTPUT), &WB, NULL);
        if (WriteFile == 0) {
            fprintf(file_pointer, "WriteFile FAILED");
        }
        else {
            fprintf(file_pointer, "WriteFile SUCCEEDED");
        }
        fprintf(file_pointer, "%p", Original_VA_WriteFile);
        //fclose(file_pointer);
        return Original_VA_WriteFile(hFile, lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToWrite, lpNumberOfBytesWritten, lpOverlapped);
    }
    */
    fopen_s(&write_file, "C:\\Users\\Mikail\\Documents\\outputinjectedDLL7.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(write_file, "test");
    return Original_VA_WriteFile(hFile, lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToWrite, lpNumberOfBytesWritten, lpOverlapped);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE Base_DLL_Address, DWORD Reason_CALL, LPVOID Reserved)
{
    switch (Reason_CALL)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:

        MessageBoxA(NULL, "TEST", "01", MB_OK);
        Original_VA_WriteFile = WriteFile; 
        HANDLE Handle_Process = GetCurrentProcess();
        if (Handle_Process == NULL) {
            DWORD error = GetLastError();
            fprintf(file_pointer, "Handle not retrieved %s", error);
        }
        else {
            fopen_s(&file_pointer, "C:\\Users\\Mikail\\Documents\\outputinjectedDLL4.txt", "r+");
            fprintf(file_pointer, "\nVA of WriteFile_HOOK is :%p", WriteFile_HOOK);

            char* ImageBase = NULL;

            if (EnumProcessModules(Handle_Process, array_modules, sizeof(array_modules), &number_bytes) != 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < (number_bytes / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++) {
                    DWORD Module_LEN_string = GetModuleFileNameEx(Handle_Process, array_modules[i], BUFFER, sizeof(BUFFER));
                    fprintf(file_pointer, "\n%ls %p", BUFFER, array_modules[i]);
                    if (wcsstr(BUFFER, L"Notepad.exe") != NULL) {
                        ImageBase = array_modules[i];
                        fprintf(file_pointer, "\nImagebase: %p", ImageBase);

                        PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeaders = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)ImageBase;
                        fprintf(file_pointer, "\ndosHeader: %p", dosHeaders);
                        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)ImageBase + dosHeaders->e_lfanew);
                        fprintf(file_pointer, "\nntHeader: %p", ntHeaders);
                        IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ImportsDirectory_RVA = ntHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT];
                        PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR Import_Directory = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(ImportsDirectory_RVA.VirtualAddress + (DWORD_PTR)ImageBase);
                        fprintf(file_pointer, "\nImport Directory: %p", Import_Directory);

                        while (Import_Directory->Name != NULL)
                        {
                            char* Module_AA = (char*)(ImageBase + Import_Directory->Name);

                            PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA OFT_value = (LPCSTR)Import_Directory->OriginalFirstThunk; //RVA_OFT
                            PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA PointerModule_AA_OFT = (LPCSTR)Import_Directory->OriginalFirstThunk + (DWORD_PTR)ImageBase; //VA_OFT
                            PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA PointerModule_AA_FT = (LPCSTR)Import_Directory->FirstThunk + (DWORD_PTR)ImageBase; //(R)VA_FT

                            if (strstr(Module_AA, "KERNEL32.dll") != NULL) {
                                fprintf(file_pointer, "\nLibrary: %s\nRVA OFT: %p\nVA OFT: %p\nVA FT: %p", Module_AA, OFT_value, PointerModule_AA_OFT, PointerModule_AA_FT);
                                while (PointerModule_AA_FT->u1.Function != NULL) {

                                    PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA Win32_Function_AA_FT = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)PointerModule_AA_FT->u1.Function; //AA WIN32 Function
                                    PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA Win32_Function_RVA_OFT = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)PointerModule_AA_OFT->u1.Function; //RVA WIN32 Function

                                    if (Win32_Function_RVA_OFT == 0xEB436) {
                                        fprintf(file_pointer, "\nWriteFile FT: %p \nWriteFile OFT: %p", Win32_Function_AA_FT, Win32_Function_RVA_OFT);

                                        DWORD OR_Access_Rights;

                                        int VirtualProtect_Memory = VirtualProtect(&Win32_Function_AA_FT->u1.Function, sizeof(DWORD_PTR), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &OR_Access_Rights);
                                        if (VirtualProtect_Memory == 0){
                                            fprintf(file_pointer, "\nVirtualProtectMemory FAILED");
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            fprintf(file_pointer, "\nVirtualProtectMemory SUCCEEDED: %d", VirtualProtect_Memory);
                                        }
                                        // Original_VA_WriteFile = (Func_Pointer)Win32_Function_AA_FT;
                                        // fprintf(file_pointer, "\nOriginal VA WriteFile: %p", Original_VA_WriteFile);

                                        fprintf(file_pointer, "\nOriginal VA WriteFile entry: %p and %p", Win32_Function_AA_FT->u1.Function, Win32_Function_AA_FT->u1.AddressOfData);
                                        Win32_Function_AA_FT->u1.Function = (DWORD_PTR)WriteFile_HOOK;
                                        //Win32_Function_RVA_OFT->u1.Function = (DWORD_PTR)RVA_OFT_CH;
                                        if (Win32_Function_AA_FT->u1.Function == (DWORD_PTR)WriteFile_HOOK) {
                                            //fprintf(file_pointer, "\nHOOK COMPLETED \nVA Entry WriteFileHOOK %p and OFT %p", Win32_Function_AA_FT->u1.Function, Win32_Function_RVA_OFT);
                                            fprintf(file_pointer, "\nAddress stored in IAT %p", Win32_Function_AA_FT->u1.Function);
                                            fprintf(file_pointer, "\nAddress of WriteFile_HOOK %p", WriteFile_HOOK);  
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            fprintf(file_pointer, "\nHOOK FAILED");
                                        }
                                    }

                                    PointerModule_AA_OFT++;
                                }
                            }
                            Import_Directory++;
                        }                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
                    
        //break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: The loader lock is [real](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices).